# When is the type parameter determined when I use type bounding in static methods?

Tags: java, static

When is the type parameter determined when I use type bounding in static methods?

e.g.:

```
public class TypeClass{
    public static <U> U get(U arg0){
        return arg0;
    }
}
```

main:

```
String str1 = TypeClass.get("dummy");
```

At which time is U declared?

Answer (score 0):

Generics aren't available at runtime. In the compile time type system, type arguments are present, and used for type checking. In the runtime type system, type arguments are absent, and therefore not checked.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind: *generics* are (almost) only about **compile time**.

The compiler comes across:

```
String str1 = TypeClass.get("dummy");
```

And finds that you are invoking a static method that uses type parameters. Then its type inference algorithm kicks - and finds that you pass in a String; so that `U` would be `String`. At runtime, everything is `Object` anyway.

That is all there is to this.

Comment: Thans! But Integer int1 = TypeClass.get(new Integer(1)); also works. So even if it's a static method, I can use different types during runtime?

Comment: Again: at compile time, the compiler determines: you are passing in an Integer, so an Integer has to come back. At runtime, there are just Objects passed (and casted).

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
public class TypeClass{
    public static <U> U get(U arg0){
        return arg0;
    }
}

String str1 = TypeClass.get("dummy");
```

becomes, when compiled:

```
public class TypeClass{
    public static Object get(Object arg0){
        return arg0;
    }
}

String str1 = (String) TypeClass.get("dummy");
```

The only way in which the type variable is "declared" is when you write `<U>`. The compiler infers a type satisfying the bounds, and inserts a necessary casts *at the call site*.